# How can I check whether my Mac OS El Captain network is tracked?

Tags: network, privacy

I want to check how (if) and what of my files and network data is logged when using my MacBook offsite. This is a work computer and I know almost all data is tracked when I am onsite. How can I check if this happens when I am offsite not using the VPN (company provided).

Can someone tell me how this is tracked by IT, is there something like syncing drives to a network drive whenever a particular person gets connected on Office network?

Answer (score 3):

Best bet is to install a program like [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html):

It comes with a time limited (first three hours after booting - the network monitors expires after 30 days) free trial of the full app but you can always use the network monitor to see what connections are happening too / what is using bandwidth.